# Tree animation using HTML5

Tags: html

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27279124/4711865) post

on how to animate a tree using HTML5, I want to animate the same tree over and over again every time, I tried messing with the code a bit without success, can anyone point me in the right direction or help?

Comment: Do you mean loop the animation or make multiple trees?

Comment: It is using pseudorandom numbers. If you want the same result every time then you either need to seed it with the same seed every time or store the sequence.

Comment: @Alex W, I want the same animation effect that the tree starts from bottoms and grows branches, then leaves until it ends. I want that animation to produce the exact same tree EVERY time.

Comment: @TimSeguine, I figured as much, but my testing didn't work... i'll try again tomorrow when i'm fresh.

Comment: Put some code on the page 'Brah'.

Comment: I ran accross https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom which is a drop in repacement for Math.random that allows seeding.

Comment: Would be nice if you could explain more, I dislike githubs without demos of their work, the documentation is not very good.

Comment: All you have to do is include the js and call `Math.seedrandom('arbitrary seed');` at the beginning of every sequence of random numbers that should be repeatable.